# Datatables setting default options

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10

This is how I initialize a dataTable

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 0,
      "searchable": false
    } ]
} );
```

Can I do something like below?

```
var mytable = $('#example').dataTable();

mytable.columnDefs({
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 0,
      "searchable": false
    } ]
} );
```

This is because I want to define a default initialization in a js file that I include in page where I need dataTables, but still be able to modify few options to be able to customize few thing per page.

Comment: your $('#example').dataTable() and mytable.columnDefs() are equal....
What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: columnDefs() there is no such api in datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way I can see of doing this is:

Replace your initialisation of the datatable with:

```
var mytable;
function initialiseSpecificDatatable(options) {
    mytable = $('#example').dataTable(options);
    return mytable; // Return table so locally you can use it
}
```

Then wherever you specify/change the options

```
var table = initialiseSpecificDatatable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 0,
        "searchable": false
    }]
});
```

You may want to add a `.destroy()` to the creation function in case you want to recreate the table. To do so, simply add:

```
try {
    $(mytable).DataTable().destroy(); //Note capital D to return a DataTable API (See API docs)
} catch (e) {
    // Fails if the table was not a DataTable at the time
}
```

At the start of the `initialiseSpecificDatatable` function.

Comment: In `initialiseSpecificDatatable` the databtable is defined with existing options, I just want to append options to it if it is not present, update option value if it is already there. The way you are passing options what will it do?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://datatables.net/manual/options#Setting-defaults) is what I found for setting defaults, and will be using as a solution to my problem. (Check the use of [jquery extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) that is used to merge content of objects)

```
// Disable search and ordering by default
$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    searching: false,
    ordering:  false
} );

// For this specific table we are going to enable searching except on first (0th) column
// (ordering is still disabled)
$('#example').DataTable( {
    searching: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        "targets": 0,
        "searchable": false
    }]
} );
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but instead of working on the dataTables defaults directly you should make a copy and work on that -> `var params = $.extend({}, $.fn.dataTable.defaults);` now you can manipulate `params` without changing the original dataTables defaults.